# webdriver findElement inside findElements

Tags: java, selenium

i am wondering if there is an efficient way to find element inside list of elements
example :

```
WebElement menuItem;
List<WebElement> allMenuItems = driver.findElements(By.className("x-menu-list-item"));      
    for(WebElement item : allMenuItems){
        if(item.getText().equals("aaa"){
                      menuItem = item;
                      break;
                    }
    }
menuItem.click();
```

so instead of looping through to find element based on text, is there an efficient way to find element from the list of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can build your initial query to find your element immediatelly.

If you don't need to search by text, you can mostly use CSS selectors for maximum readability and efficiency.

If, however, you need to search by text, you must use an XPath expression.

For example, your code could be simply

```
WebElement menuItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'x-list-menu-item') and contains(text(), 'aaaa')]"));
```

Note that the class finding with XPath is not exactly correct. Search for it online to find the right construct.

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to avoid using By.xpath, but i guess like you said, if i need to search by text then i have to use xpath

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. It's either XPath or your solution.